# Javascript: Remove Child when using document.write

Tags: javascript

I want to have something like this:

```
var abc1 = document.write('<html>HTMLPAGECONTENTHERE</html>');

function removepage(){
abc1.parentNode.removeChild(abc1);
}

removepage();
```

Comment: And? What's your question?  Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

That won't work; `document.write` doesn't return anything.

You should use the DOM APIs instead (`createElement()` and `appendChild()`), or, more easily, jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` inserts a stream of HTML directly into the page. It has no useful return value.

If you want to manipulate what it outputs via DOM, then you have to have a known quantity to match with `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName` or some other method for getting HTML Element Nodes from a DOM.